# i can not import swiftHTTP (rapidAPI)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rapidapi

i add SwiftHTTP.xcodeproject to my project,

in build phases: i add 4 SwiftHTTP.framework

ViewController ---   import SwiftHTTP

error = "No such module SwiftHTTP"

both Xcode 6.4 and 7.1 have this error

Answer (score 0):

Do either in the settings of your project:

Depending if you want to "include the library in your final release or not"

Without, just use it whilst debugging and coding:
1) Under **General Settings** Where it says "linked frameworks and libraries" at the bottom, click on the + just below it and then choose the framework from the list that appears

With it:
2) Under **General Settings** Where it says "EMBEDDED binaries" at the bottom, click on the + just below it and then choose the framework from the list that appears

I'd suggest just sticking with "linking it" rather than embedding it until you actually release your code.

Cheers,

A